# Gap between heading and navigation

Tags: nav, heading

Beginner here.

I'm trying to figure out how to put 5 elements on my nav bar. 
First element is heading and the other for are li's.

Hopefully someone can help!

I want to get the following result:
[each element fills up 20% of the width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILlkj.png)
But what I get is this.
 [Not equally distributed space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9flm.png)

Below the snippet.

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: slateblue;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: white;
  width: 960px;
}

#navigation h2 {
  display: inline;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #555;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffa0a0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffa0a0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pagename</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navigation">
    <h2>Pagename</h2>
    <ul>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Services</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Portfolio</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contacts</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does my answer suit your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) feature.
I slightly edited your code to

- replace `ul` by a `div` element (since you don't use `li` items)
- replaced body width by 100% to make it working with the snippet display (this one is just for a good-looking display in the answer, you can replace it by your pixel value. Also `div` `width` style is by default set to 100% (it's a block displayed item), you don't need to set it for the `div#navigation` element.

**Update.** I added the Pagename heading to the equally distributed items to fit the design you want (according to the screenshot).

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: slateblue;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: white;
}



#navigation #nav-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content:space-between;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation h2 {
  background-color: #555;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffa0a0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation #nav-items a {
  background-color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffa0a0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pagename</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navigation">
    <div id="nav-items">
      <h2>Pagename</h2>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Services</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Portfolio</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contacts</li>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```